# Changing <div> CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>` element reference in JavaScript as follows:

```
custom_div = document.createElement("div")
```

I want to change the `position` of this element to `absolute` and set the `bottom` alignment to `0`, through JavaScript. I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Where is your code? Have you search the jQuery API?

Comment: You just made an element, unless you put it somewhere it doesn't really matter how you style it, but it would be `custom_div.style.position = 'absolute'` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549885/unable-to-set-absolute-position-for-my-divs-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
document.getElementById("div#example").style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById("div#example").style.bottom="0";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are SO many ways to do this, but direct manipulation of DOM is not recommended.  Either use [CSS classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) or try [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/).